# Multiple Commands Within a Lisp Routine

Tags: lisp, autocad, data-extraction, autolisp

Please help me with a small issue.

I have the following .lsp and it needs to be slightly updated, but i can't seem to find a solution yet. I want it to zoom extents and then select all texts with colour 7 and run `TTT` command (this is a custom function that exports selected text in an Excel sheet).

In my testing, it stops before selecting the text and ask me to select the desired text. I assume it's a problem with the `ssget` function.

```
(defun C:123 (/ SS)
  (command "_.Zoom" "E")
  (if (setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "*TEXT")(62 . 7))))
    (C:TTT)
  )
)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The successful operation of your program will be dependent on the definition of the `c:ttt` function, specifically whether or not this function has been written to accept an implied selection.

Ideally, the `c:ttt` function would be restructured as a function accepting a single selection set parameter, such that you could evaluate the function and pass your `ss` selection set variable.

However, without knowledge of the definition of the `c:ttt` function, the best that I could suggest would be to provide an implied selection in the following manner:

```
(defun c:123 ( / ss )
    (command "_.zoom" "_e")
    (if
        (setq ss
            (ssget "_X"
                (list
                   '(0 . "TEXT")
                   '(62 . 7)
                    (if (= 1 (getvar 'cvport))
                        (cons 410 (getvar 'ctab))
                       '(410 . "Model")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        (progn
            (sssetfirst nil ss)
            (C:TTT)
        )
        (princ "\nNo single-line text with object colour set to white found in the current layout/viewport.")
    )
    (princ)
)
```

You will note that I have also revised the selection criteria for your `ssget` expression to only consider white single-line text residing in the current viewport/layout to ensure that the implied selection operates as expected.

**EDIT:** I would suggest the following revision to your code:

```
(defun c:123 ( / s )
    (command "_.zoom" "_e")
    (if (setq s (ssget "_X" '((0 . "TEXT") (62 . 7))))
        (ttt s)
        (princ "\nNo single-line text found with object colour set to white.")
    )
    (princ)
)

(defun c:ttt ( / s )
    (if (setq s (ssget '((0 . "TEXT")))) (ttt s))
    (princ)
)

(defun ttt ( sel / des fnm idx )
    (if
        (and sel
            (setq fnm (vl-filename-mktemp nil nil ".csv"))
            (setq des (open fnm "w"))
        )
        (progn
            (repeat (setq idx (sslength sel))
                (setq idx (1- idx))
                (write-line (LM:csv-addquotes (cdr (assoc 1 (entget (ssname sel idx)))) ",") des)
            )
            (close des)
            (startapp "explorer" fnm)
        )
    )
)

(defun LM:csv-addquotes ( str sep / pos )
    (cond
        (   (wcmatch str (strcat "*[`" sep "\"]*"))
            (setq pos 0)    
            (while (setq pos (vl-string-position 34 str pos))
                (setq str (vl-string-subst "\"\"" "\"" str pos)
                      pos (+ pos 2)
                )
            )
            (strcat "\"" str "\"")
        )
        (   str   )
    )
)

(princ)
```

Here, I have defined a new function `ttt` accepting a selection set argument comprised of single-line text objects, and successively writing the content of each text object in the set to a temporary CSV file (though, this could ultimately be any text format file, since only one column is used).

The new function is then evaluated by your `c:ttt` function and `c:123` function - the former prompting for a selection per your existing command, and the latter automatically processing all white text found in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Lee Mac, that’s an honour to get help from you you probably don’t know, but your site helped me many times before and i want to thank you, you’re doing a tremendous job About that TTT function, i have it from a friend, but probably is a code made by you:))

Please see below TTT function:

```
    (defun LM:writecsv ( lst csv / des sep )
(if (setq des (open csv "w"))
(progn
(setq sep (cond ((vl-registry-read "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International" "sList")) (",")))
(foreach row lst (write-line (LM:lst->csv row sep) des))
(close des)
t
)
)
)
(defun LM:lst->csv ( lst sep )
(if (cdr lst)
(strcat (LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep) sep (LM:lst->csv (cdr lst) sep))
(LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep)
)
)

(defun LM:csv-addquotes ( str sep / pos )
(cond
( (wcmatch str (strcat "*[`" sep "\"]*"))
(setq pos 0)
(while (setq pos (vl-string-position 34 str pos))
(setq str (vl-string-subst "\"\"" "\"" str pos)
pos (+ pos 2)
)
)
(strcat "\"" str "\"")
)
( str )
)
)

(defun C:ttt(/ lst ss i el x fn)
(setq lst (list) ss (ssget (list (cons 0 "TEXT"))) )
(repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
(setq x (ssname ss (setq i (1- i))))
(setq el (entget x))
(if (= (cdr (assoc 0 el)) "TEXT")
(setq lst (append lst (list (list (cdr (assoc 1 el))))))
)
)
(setq fn (vl-filename-mktemp nil nil ".csv"))
(if (and lst (LM:WriteCSV (reverse lst) fn))
(startapp "explorer" fn)
)
)
```

In principal, i want it to zoom extents => select all texts with colour 7 => run this TTT command and export the selected text in a .csv file. If you know any other way to achieve this , other then what i pointed to, it's just as good.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words Nick, I appreciate your positive feedback for my contributions. I've revised my answer to include a suggestion of how I would personally structure this function, and your two custom commands. Just as a heads up, note that this site is a Q&A site and does not operate like a forum, and therefore your 'reply' will likely be removed since it does not constitute an answer to your question - instead, in future, you should edit the content of your question or comment on my answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! It does exactly what i wanted! One more little thing, if i'm not asking too much :) Can the code be updated so the file exported will always be "DRAW.xlsx" or at least extension ".xlsx" ? And thanks for the heads up regarding replies, i'll keep that in mind. Cheers!

Comment: Changing the code to 'DRAW.csv' is a relatively easy modification - simply change `(setq fnm (vl-filename-mktemp nil nil ".csv"))` to a filename/filepath of your choice. However, whilst CSV is a plain text format, XLSX is a binary format and therefore its creation requires interfacing with the installed Excel application; consequently this requires significantly more code to accomplish. As a compromise, you could write the file as a plain text XLSX and let Excel do the heavy lifting when opening the file, but users will receive a warning when the file is opened.

Comment: Thank you, Lee! I modified the line as follows: `(setq fnm (vl-filename-base "DRAW.csv.csv"))` and it does what i want. Thanks again and have a great day. Cheers!

Comment: Note that that expression could become: `(setq fnm "DRAW.csv")` You're welcome!